# Getting error of "Can't serialize user", but the passport.serializeUser is never called

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, passport.js, passport-local

My struggle with adding passport to my application continues! I got it so that I no longer get the crazy huge errors that I saw before, but the app just kept outputting `{}`. So after putting in as many `console.log()` statements as I could find, I've narrowed it down to the fact that the application says it can't serialize the user object, but as far as I can tell the `passport.serializeUser()` function is never called.

***[GitHub link with all files (other than node modules)](https://github.com/jhechtf/hms-students/)***

Granted, I am not 100% on how passport works, and I'm super new to Node but have experience with other languages for years, so if I need to I can just do this by hand, but I'd much prefer using passport as it allows for me to eventually use Facebook and Google auth without having to remake the wheel, so to speak.

### Error

Here is the exact error:

> Passport Strategy  jhechtf (password)
>
> user found
>
> passwords are good
>
> Passport Authenticate :  jhechtf
>
> Passport Authenticate Err:  null
>
> Passport Authenticate Info:  { message: 'Logged In Successfully' }
>
> AuthController Error:  [Error: Failed to serialize user into session]

Now I've googled "Failed to serialize user into session passport.js" in almost every term imaginable but every time it always seems to be something with the `deserializeUser` instead of `serializeUser`. The one thing that struck me was that my `console.log()` calls from the `serializeUser()` aren't seen at any point in time.

## AuthController.js

```
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = {

    _config: {
        actions: false,
        shortcuts: false,
        rest: false
    },

    login: function (req, res) {

        passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
            if(user==false){
                return res.status(403).send(info);
            }

            console.log("Passport Authenticate : ", user.username);
            console.log("Passport Authenticate Err: ", err);
            console.log("Passport Authenticate Info: ", info);
            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) {  
                    console.log("AuthController Error: " , err);
                    return res.status(401).send(err);
                }
                //Assume a correct login?

                var red = req.session.redirectTo || '/'; 
                //get the redirection value if it was set.
                delete req.session.redirectTo;
                //Now that we've got it, delete it.
                res.redirect(red);
                //redirect
            });


        })(req, res);
    },

    logout: function (req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    }
};
```

## config/passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log("Serialize User (passport.js) ", user);
//  if(user==false || user == undefined){
//      done({error:'user is not a user object, but is false or undefined'});
//  }
//  done(null, user.user_id);
    done(null,user.user_id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    console.log("ID COMING IN AS: ", id);
    Users.findOne({
        user_id: id
    }, function (err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'user_password'
    },
    function (un, password, done) {
        console.log("Passport Strategy ", un,password);

        Users.findOne({
            username: un
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("USER.FINDONE ERROR ", err);
                return done(err,false,{message:'Can\'t find user'});
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Incorrect Username <small>Are you sure you signed up?</small>'
                });
            }
            console.log('user found');
            if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.user_password)) {
                console.log('passwords are good');
                return done(null, user, {
                    message: 'Logged In Successfully'
                });
            } else {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Invalid Password'
                });
            }

        });
    }
));
```

## config/http.js (just in case)

```
passportInit: require('passport').initialize(),
passportSession: require('passport').session(),

order: [
    'startRequestTimer',
    'cookieParser',
    'session',
    'myRequestLogger',
    'passportInit',
    'passportSession',
    'bodyParser',
    'handleBodyParserError',
    'compress',
    'methodOverride',
    'poweredBy',
    'router',
    'www',
    'favicon',
    '404',
    '500'
  ],
```

## SQL for the table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `user_password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_salt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `user_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_display_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

hanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Hi again! I compared your files to my working passport setup and managed to narrow down the problem a bit. I'll try to figure out exactly which part that causes the issue.

Comment: Nope, the errors I got with your code were only due to differences in model and attribute names. Once I fixed them to match my model, passport authentication worked just fine. If you add your project to Github, I can have another go later, if you want.

Comment: I would appreciate as I am especially stumped. out of frustration I made a new sails project and just added in these files, the only thing I didn't do was have my `Users` model accidentally mapped to `User` (type when doing `sails generate new api`. I'll get them up in a second.

Comment: [GitHub](https://github.com/jhechtf/hms-students/) Hopefully I've remembered to update the package.json file. If you get errors out of something please let me know as I didn't include my `node_modules` folder as it was gigantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two sets of libraries for Passport authentication: the `sails-auth` package (which includes a few models, controllers, routes etc.) and the `passport` + `passport-local` packages (just the plain Passport libraries). It seems you're actually not using `sails-auth` at all, but nevertheless it hooks into your application and makes Passport configurations of its own. I guess that's why your `passport.serializeUser()` function is never "activated".

Remove `sails-auth` from your `package.json` file and from your `node_modules/` directory to fix your setup.

Comment: I don't even remember installing `sails-auth` wth! Thank you so much for your time and patience Viktor.